# Describing algorithms to implement higher level operations in terms of the lower level operations

Tags: python, algorithm

[image]

My question concerns problem (b). This is my attempt:

```html
def shift_left(D,k)
    for j = 0 to k:
      x_current = D.delete_first() //this remove and return first item
      D.insert_last(x_current)
     
    return D
```

The answer key was given the following for the solution. I am just trying to figure out if my solution is correct. I know this solution key uses recursion. Does my solution work as well?

[image]

Comment: You should also make sure your code is free from compiler errors (there's one in your code now).

Comment: That is why you downvote?

Comment: It's only temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code solves the problem in a desired way, it is concise which is good.

#### Some comments

Your design limits the shifting to `k > len(D) - 1`, if it is your intention, then it is perfect otherwise this could be solved by doing

```py
def shift_left(D, k):
    k = k % len(D) #the modulus makes k to be in the positive integer domain
    if (k < 1):
        return
    x = D.delete_first()
    D.insert_last(x)
    #it could be done with a for and saves recursively comparing k each time
    shift_left(D, k-1)
```

#### An alternative

```py
def shift_left(D, k):
    k = k % len(D)
    if (k < 1):
        return
    #avoids recursion, which saves recursive calls and passing parameters
    #(could be done using a while)
    for i in range(0,k)
        x = D.delete_first()
        D.insert_last(x)
```